# Exporting from PHP to Excel - cell formatting

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, export

I am exporting data from a database to an Excel file using PHP and a Codeigniter to_excel helper.

Everything is working correctly, except I have a field that contains data in the format of **1-1**, **2-1** etc. When I open the file in Excel, Excel is automatically formatting this data as a date field so that it appears **01-Jan**, **02-Jan** etc.

Is there a way to force Excel not to format this data as a date field?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Preface the data with a single apostrophe so that Excel treats it as text. This needs to be done before it is opened in Excel.